# What is the difference between <Route /> vs <Route> </Route> in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using the `react-router-dom` and creating some routes in my application. Can anyone please explain me the specific usages of  and  . What will be the difference affect in the rendering if there are any. I will include a sample code snippet.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/home" component={App} />

    <Route path='/about'>
      <About />
    </Route>
    
  </Router>
);
```

I tried both and both are working fine. But I was unable to find the specific usage of one over other.

Comment: Since JSX is a way of embedding Markup expressions to describe the UI, the question looks like its asking about opening and closing elements and what an empty elements look like in Markup.

Answer (score 2):

The `react-router-dom@5` `Route` component has 4 ways to render content. The primary method is to directly render content as the `children` prop. Note here that no [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) will be passed to the component.

```
<Route path='/about'>
  <About />
</Route>
```

The other 3 ways are to use one of the [route render methods](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods).

> The recommended method of rendering something with a `<Route>` is to use
> children elements, as shown above. There are, however, a few other
> methods you can use to render something with a `<Route>`. These are
> provided mostly for supporting apps that were built with earlier
> versions of the router before hooks were introduced.
>
> - [`<Route component>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)
> - [`<Route render>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)
> - [`<Route children>` function](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func)

Examples:

[`component`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) - Other common method, route props are implicitly passed as props to the component.

```
<Route path='/about' component={About} />
```

[`render` function](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) - Alternative to pass along runtime props as well as the route props.

```
<Route path='/about' render={routeProps => <About {...routeProps} {...otherProps} />} />
```

[`children` function](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func) - Renders regardless of route match and passes route props to component to handle any conditional logic.

```
<Route path='/about' children={routeProps => <About {...routeProps} />} />
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Drew. You made it more clear to me.

Comment: <Routes>

        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
        <Route path='/post' element={<NewPost/>} />
        <Route path='/post/:id' element={<SinglePost/>} />
        <Route path='*' element={<Missing/>} />
        
      </Routes>

Comment: I found that in react-router-dom@6 we can use route like this <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />

Comment: @wmhchathuranga Yeah, RRDv6 introduced a lot of breaking changes. With the `Route` all the routed content is rendered on a single `element` prop as a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, and only other `Route` components are valid children in the case of building nested routes.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small add to [Mr. Drew Reese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75358834/12252601), the way rendering a component directly inside `<Route>` allow you to freely pass your own props inside your component (it's more familiar to the way we usually do with normal React components).

Ex: You have a page About, inside, it includes 3 tabs: "About me", "About my team", "About my blog".

```
const About = () => {
  // call APIs, handle...

  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/about-me'>
          <Me data={dataMe} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/about-team'>
          <Team data={dataTeam} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/about-blog'>
          <Blog data={dataBlog} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  )
}
```